# Diagonalization of a matrix with operators as elements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, eigenvalue, analyticity

How to diagonalize a hamiltonian matrix that has differential operators as elements? My matrix looks something like:
\begin{bmatrix}
A \frac{d^{2}}{{d\theta}^{2}}+ B_{1} & a\cos{(b\theta +c)}\\
 a\cos{(b\theta +c)} & A \frac{d^{2}}{{d\theta}^{2}}+ B_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
where A, $B_{1}$, $B_{2}$, a,b and c are all constants.
How to do I find the spectrum of eigen values for such systems. Are there any standard methods available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your matrix operate on a vector of functions (of $\theta$, in this case), and look for solutions where it produces a constant multiple of that vector. In other words, solve

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
A \dfrac{\mathrm d^{2}}{{\mathrm d\theta}^{2}} + B_{1} & & a\cos(b\theta +c) \\
 a\cos{(b\theta +c)} && A \dfrac{\mathrm d^{2}}{{\mathrm d\theta}^{2}}+ B_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
f(\theta)\vphantom{\dfrac{\mathrm d^{2}}{{\mathrm d\theta}^{2}}} \\
g(\theta)\vphantom{\dfrac{\mathrm d^{2}}{{\mathrm d\theta}^{2}}}
\end{bmatrix}
=\lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
f(\theta)\vphantom{\dfrac{\mathrm d^{2}}{{\mathrm d\theta}^{2}}} \\
g(\theta)\vphantom{\dfrac{\mathrm d^{2}}{{\mathrm d\theta}^{2}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{01}\label{eq01}       
\end{equation}
which is a coupled set of second-order differential equations for $f(\theta)$ and $g(\theta)$. To help solve this system and find values of $\lambda$ which produce periodic solutions so that there is no discontinuity in $\theta$, read about Mathieu functions.

Comment: Could someone who knows LaTeX better than I do tell me how to make the matrix brackets and the vector brackets the same height?

Comment: How can I diagonalise such a matrix? I found something called Fulton-Gouterman transformation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about that transformation. But if you can find the operator's eigenvectors and eigenvalues, you can diagonalize it. Unfortunately, I think I'm wrong about the Mathieu functions... I originally didn't notice that the $B$'s had subscripts, and when I took $B_1=B_2=B$ and decoupled the equations by looking at $f+g$ and $f-g$ I got Mathieu functions. But for the more general $B_1\ne B_2$ I get fouth-order PDEs that I don't know how to solve analytically. Are you trying to get an analytic solution or a numerical solution?

Comment: With Mathematica, I can numerically find the eigenvalues and eigenvector functions using the function NDEigensystem. For example, for $A=B2=B2=a=b=1, c=0$, I get that the first five eigenvalues are -0.2932, -0.2932, 0.405184, -1.28535, and -1.34277.

Comment: Any idea on how i could decouple them or resource where I can read about solving coupled differential equations

Comment: Yes I forgot to add a point, both the functions $ f(\theta), g(\theta)$ are having a general boundary condition:  $F (\theta +2\pi) = F(\theta)$

Comment: Yes, that periodicity is what I meant when I said “find values of $\lambda$ which produce periodic solutions”.

Comment: Decoupling them is easy if you write out the two equations. Solve one for $g$ in terms of $f$ and $\partial_\theta f$ and substitute that into the other equation. You get an equation involving only $f$, not $g$, but has fourth order derivatives.

Comment: Sorry, but  I am not able to do it with Mathematica. I am new to Mathematica, could you please guide me through this.

Comment: $\texttt{L1 = A f''[t] + B1 f[t] + a Cos[b t + c] g[t]}$

Comment: $\texttt{L2 = a Cos[b t + c] f[t] + A g''[t] + B2 g[t]}$

Comment: $\texttt{s = NDEigensystem[{L1, L2} /. {A -> 1, B1 -> 1, B2 -> 1, a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 0}, {f[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 10]}$